# What is CStringArray or CSortStringArray. And how to arrange this array in order?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

The problem is how to arrange order if i just used `CStringArray` not `CSortStringArray` the arrangement of first array sortarray is from (a to m) in order. But if i used `CSortStringArray` still the arrangement is same. And second array sortarray1 from 1.txt to 15.txt the order is always wrong either using `CStringArray` or `CSortStringArray`?

```
void CtestmfcDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
    {
        CSortStringArray sortArray;
        sortArray.Add(CString("a"));
        sortArray.Add(CString("b"));
        sortArray.Add(CString("c"));
        sortArray.Add(CString("d"));
        sortArray.Add(CString("e"));
        sortArray.Add(CString("f"));
        sortArray.Add(CString("g"));
        sortArray.Add(CString("h"));
        sortArray.Add(CString("i"));
        sortArray.Add(CString("j"));
        sortArray.Add(CString("k"));
        sortArray.Add(CString("l"));
        sortArray.Add(CString("m"));

        CSortStringArray sortArray1;

        sortArray1.Add(CString("1.txt"));
        sortArray1.Add(CString("2.txt"));
        sortArray1.Add(CString("3.txt"));
        sortArray1.Add(CString("4.txt"));
        sortArray1.Add(CString("5.txt"));
        sortArray1.Add(CString("6.txt"));
        sortArray1.Add(CString("7.txt"));
        sortArray1.Add(CString("8.txt"));
        sortArray1.Add(CString("9.txt"));
        sortArray1.Add(CString("10.txt"));
        sortArray1.Add(CString("11.txt"));
        sortArray1.Add(CString("12.txt"));
        sortArray1.Add(CString("13.txt"));
        sortArray1.Add(CString("14.txt"));
        sortArray1.Add(CString("15.txt"));



        for (int i = 0; i <= sortArray.GetUpperBound(); i++)
            {
                testbox1.AddString(sortArray[i]);
            }
            //sortArray.Sort();

            for (int j = 0; j <= sortArray1.GetUpperBound(); j++)
            {
                testbox2.AddString(sortArray1[j]);
            }

   }
```

Comment: Your second array is not wrong sorted. It compares the strings, not integers.

Comment: but output is wrong?

Comment: I do not see any output in your example. What is wrong ? More details please.

Comment: the second array output is 1,10,11,12,13,14,15,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 this is the problem.

Comment: That is not a problem. As I have already said, this is correct sorted. Please refer to my first comment. `10.txt` compared to `2.txt` == '1' < '2'

Comment: but i want 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15?

Comment: This is very basic logic thinking. Implement your own sort if you want to sort by integers, not strings. CSort`String`Array <- not Integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If minimum system requirement is Vista or higher then you can use `CompareStringEx`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "windows.h"

using namespace std;

int wmain()
{
    vector<wstring> sa;
    wchar_t temp[50];
    for (int i = 12; i > 0; i--)
    {
        wsprintf(temp, L"%d.txt", i);
        sa.push_back(temp);
    }

    struct {
        bool operator()(const wstring &a, const wstring &b) {
            return CompareStringEx(0, SORT_DIGITSASNUMBERS,
                a.c_str(), a.length(), b.c_str(), b.length(), 0, 0, 0) == CSTR_LESS_THAN;
        }
    } mysort;
    sort(sa.begin(), sa.end(), mysort);

    for (size_t i = 0, count = sa.size(); i < count; i++)
        wcout << sa[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
...
9.txt
10.txt
11.txt
12.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot expect from a String sorting algorithm that it sorts Integers.

Filename `10.txt` will return at position [0] compared to `2.txt` that it is smaller (see ascii code 49 < 50).

If you want to sort by Integers and not Strings, you have to implement your own sort algorithm.

//To remove the last extension for a file you could use this:

```
std::string RemoveLastExtension(const std::string &fileName)
{
    auto pos = fileName.rfind(".");
    if (pos == std::string::npos)
        pos = -1;
    return std::string(fileName.begin(), fileName.begin() + pos);
}
```